# Is there a "pandas" way to identify which rows from a DataFrame are not present in a merge result?

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I have two large data chunks with 2 common columns tying them together. One "should" be a subset of the other, but when I perform a merge, the final product is smaller than the subset, so I want to look at the rows in the original (as well as the ones in the subset) to see why it's failing to merge properly. It's probably some error in an upstream script, but it's possible that my newbie pandas use is in error.

I can do it the obvious way of iterating over the values of the two datasets and find ones that are missing in the merged, but I'm assuming there is a "pandas" way of doing it that is much more efficient.

```
chip_raw= pandas.read_csv(filename, names=["CHROM", "POS", "GT", "score", "rsid"], sep=" ")
seq_data= pandas.read_csv(seq_filename, names=["CHROM", "POS", "vcf_gt", "gq"], sep="\t")
merged = pandas.merge(chip_raw, seq_data, on=["CHROM", "POS"], how="inner")
```

I've edited to show an example of how the data relate to one another. I have GT, score and rsid in chip_raw that are tied uniquely to a CHROM and POS (these two columns together identify uniqueness). Then, I have vcf_gt and gq which come from a different file. I'd like to see what is in chip_raw that isn't in merged, and the same for seq_data/merged.

I'm just curious about using pandas to do it, since I am learning pandas and it seems like something that the library will do more efficiently than iterating over each item and seeing if it's present in merged.

Comment: Please show some data, and small sample of code illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, simply inspecting the result of an `outer` merge for `NaN` will do it.

```
In [119]: dfrm
Out[119]:
          A           B         C  D
0 -1.312700    0.760710  1.044006  0
1 -0.792521   -0.076913  0.087334  1
2 -0.557738    0.982031  1.365357  2
3  1.013947  100.000000 -0.356652  3
4  1.278278  100.000000  0.550492  4
5  0.116599  100.000000 -1.290245  5
6 -1.808143   -0.818014  0.713614  6
7  0.233726  100.000000  0.561103  7
8  2.344671  100.000000 -0.759296  8
9 -1.658047    1.756503 -0.996620  9

In [120]: dfrm1 = dfrm.copy()

In [121]: dfrm1.ix[3, 'D'] = 888

In [122]: dfrm1
Out[122]:
          A           B         C    D
0 -1.312700    0.760710  1.044006    0
1 -0.792521   -0.076913  0.087334    1
2 -0.557738    0.982031  1.365357    2
3  1.013947  100.000000 -0.356652  888
4  1.278278  100.000000  0.550492    4
5  0.116599  100.000000 -1.290245    5
6 -1.808143   -0.818014  0.713614    6
7  0.233726  100.000000  0.561103    7
8  2.344671  100.000000 -0.759296    8
9 -1.658047    1.756503 -0.996620    9

In [123]: pandas.merge(dfrm, dfrm1, left_on='D', right_on='D', how='outer')
Out[123]:
         A_x         B_x       C_x    D       A_y         B_y       C_y
0  -1.312700    0.760710  1.044006    0 -1.312700    0.760710  1.044006
1  -0.792521   -0.076913  0.087334    1 -0.792521   -0.076913  0.087334
2  -0.557738    0.982031  1.365357    2 -0.557738    0.982031  1.365357
3   1.013947  100.000000 -0.356652    3       NaN         NaN       NaN
4   1.278278  100.000000  0.550492    4  1.278278  100.000000  0.550492
5   0.116599  100.000000 -1.290245    5  0.116599  100.000000 -1.290245
6  -1.808143   -0.818014  0.713614    6 -1.808143   -0.818014  0.713614
7   0.233726  100.000000  0.561103    7  0.233726  100.000000  0.561103
8   2.344671  100.000000 -0.759296    8  2.344671  100.000000 -0.759296
9  -1.658047    1.756503 -0.996620    9 -1.658047    1.756503 -0.996620
10       NaN         NaN       NaN  888  1.013947  100.000000 -0.356652
```

Using `right` or `left` can also help identify which side of the merge is creating the problem.

Comment: Great suggestion. I hadn't thought about using an outer join for this, but that is perfect.